# Currency Symbol for various languages in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, currency, cultureinfo

My application supports multi language including English ,Chinese, Hindi Language. I need to display the currency symbol in the textbox based on the culture selected. How can this be done?

Comment: Please read [Using Cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647353.aspx#diforwc-ch07_usingcultures)

Comment: The proposed duplicate doesn't show how to get the currency symbol(e.g. `$`) for a given culture, the accepted answer only shows how to get the three-character symbol(e.g. `USD`) of the **current** culture/region.

Answer (score 16):

You can create a `CultureInfo` object via constructor or `CreateSpecificCulture`. Then you can use it's `NumberFormat` property and [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx):

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");    // german
string currencySymbol = culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol; // €

culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hi-IN");     // Hindi 
currencySymbol = culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;     //  ₹
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol`

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = ci.NumberFormat;
nfi.CurrencySymbol
```

See [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx)